# How to Enable JavaScript Code Formatter with 'content_for' helper for RubyMine 4.0

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, rubymine

I'm using RubyMine 4.0.3 for Mac.
When I writing ERB view templates and write inline javascript, 'content_for :javascript' helper is not highlighted and formatted as javascript.
Like below:

```
<% content_for :javascript do %>
/* JavaScript code */
<% end %>
```

How to enable RubyMine's JavaScript code formatter on Rails rule?
I found that 'script' tag is highlighted collectly, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/* JavaScript code */
</script>
```

But it is not Rails style isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible right now, I've [submitted a feature request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-10969), star/vote.